# Android: Create a CheckedTextView dynamically

Tags: android, checkedtextview

How can you dynamically create a CheckedTextView in android [without creating a new implementation]?

It seems CheckedTextView is **abstract** ... (which does not make any sense at all) because I keep getting the compile time error: *"Cannot instantiate the type CheckedTextView"*

**Using** Android 1.5

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs, the class is not abstract and has constructors. Presumably, therefore, you can call:

```
new CheckedTextView(this);
```

where `this` is your `Activity`, and get a `CheckedTextView`.

Have you run into problems using this?

Comment: You Cannot instantiate the type CheckedTextView

Comment: android.widget.CheckedTextView tv=new android.widget.CheckedTextView(this); works just fine. I just compiled it and ran it and encountered no compiler or runtime errors. So, yes, you can instantiate CheckedTextView. This is on Android 2.0.1.

Comment: I did the same, the check box was missing in it.

Comment: @arul checkbox is missing by default you can add using `setCheckMarkDrawable` I think plus you have to change the listview mode to something other than none.